# Remove unwanted URL segments in Codeigniter site_url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

On the page whose URL is "abc.com/en/login/create_member" using site_url('login') produces a link to "abc.com/en/login/create_member", but the desired URL is "abc.com/en/login/"

I've included the link code and an excerpt from my routes.php file

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Code:

```
<a class="link_grad_button" href="<?php site_url('login'); ?>">Login</a></div>
```

Route Excerpt:

```
$route[$prepended_lang.'login/(:any)'] = 'login/$1';
// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|br)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
$route['default_controller'] = 'landing';
// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|br)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Comment: are you using any multi lang library?

Comment: Try to remove `/$1` from `$route[$prepended_lang.'login/(:any)'] = 'login/$1';`... Check if this works

Comment: That did it and I realized that I simply missing an echo so the link was just using the current URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you add language on the link like

```
<a class="link_grad_button" href="<?php site_url('en/login'); ?>">Login</a></div>
```

So, your current expression on your route.php works. i.e.

```
$route[$prepended_lang.'login/(:any)'] = 'login/$1';
```

**OR**

Simply, remove `$prepended_lang.` from your route.php expression like:

```
$route['login/(:any)'] = 'login/$1';
```

This above expression works only when you have a function parameter like

```
site_url('login/index')
```

where index works as parameter for `(:any)`, so in case your url is `site_url('login')` only, you have to add:

```
$route['login'] = 'login';
```

before the above expression.

Actually these two expressions are not required on route.php but because of your appended language, these two expressions seems mandatory.